# Login process using parse

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, authentication, parse-platform

We are tried  user registration and login ,registration successfully completed. Now we are trying to Login our code like this

```
 function login() {
        var name    =  $('#name').val( );
      var email  =  $('#email').val( );
     var parseAPPID = "OUq3bUxVOH7T7bLQpl1zh73VZjYp1gtvA7i2RcFS";
    var parseJSID = "Xai30ljTmpvOP8qAYFTBKPR3bh8rLoiqusURLLIr";
    Parse.initialize(parseAPPID, parseJSID);
    Parse.User.logIn(name ,email ,{
            success: function(user) {
    console.log("success");

    }, error: function(user, error) {
                alert("Failed to login: " + error.message);
            }
        });

    }
```

we are getting error like i.e `POST https://api.parse.com/1/login 404 (Not Found)` .Any one tell me what wrong in our code.

Comment: I never used Parse. But I know they are 'closing': http://blog.parse.com/announcements/moving-on/, just in case you didn't know.

Comment: check network tab, it might be not a 404...

Comment: Just remember that, parse is shutting down: http://blog.parse.com/announcements/moving-on/